# Check multiple fields exists

Tags: elasticsearch

[The Elasticsearch Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) allows me to find documents that has certain field exists:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "exists" : { "field" : "firstname" }
    }
}
```

But it seems only work for one field exists, how to check 2 fields exist? For example, I'd like to find users that has both `firstname` and `lastname` fields exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do that by wrapping the two exists in `filter` clause or `must` clause as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "firstname"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "lastname"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Using in `filter` clause will give the same output as by `must` clause. The only difference will be the one with filter will not calculate score while the one with must will calculate score. Use as per your needs. For more on this read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html).

**Using must:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "firstname"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "lastname"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think doing it using the filter is faster, am I right?

Comment: @Kourosh Yes filter will be faster as it doen't require to calculate score.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!